# Adding of PHP url to AJAX request only works outside WordPress folder

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a php url in my ajax request but it's not working.

The code:

This works (But is not my idea way). It works with the file inside the public_html folder.

Scenario 1:

When I added the correct url to where I have added the php file, it doesn't work and pagination stops.

```
<script>
     // Home Pagination
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize with the current page
        var currentPage = <?php echo $current_page; ?>;
        
        
        // Load matches for the initial page
        loadMatches(currentPage);

        $('.pagination-link').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).data('page');
            loadMatches(page);
        });

        // Toggle the visibility of tables when a button is clicked
        $('.toggle-table').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.match-table').toggle(); // Toggle the associated table
        });

        function loadMatches(page) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'wp-content/plugins/matches/ajax-matches.php',
                data: { page: page }, // Send the page parameter
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#matches-container').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error loading matches.');
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Scenario 2:

```
<script>
     // Home Pagination
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize with the current page
        var currentPage = <?php echo $current_page; ?>;
        
        
        // Load matches for the initial page
        loadMatches(currentPage);

        $('.pagination-link').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).data('page');
            loadMatches(page);
        });

        // Toggle the visibility of tables when a button is clicked
        $('.toggle-table').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.match-table').toggle(); // Toggle the associated table
        });

        function loadMatches(page) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'ajax-matches.php',
                data: { page: page }, // Send the page parameter
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#matches-container').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error loading matches.');
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

I have tried many times. Some of what I tried but didn't work:
Adding a variable
`var ajax_target = "<?php echo plugins_url('/matches/ajax-matches.php', __FILE__); ?>";`

Your help will go a long way!

Comment: You should not be targeting any PHP script file within your plugin folder directly from the client side to begin with here - that is against WP's "philosophy", when it comes to AJAX. Your plugin should set up a proper AJAX endpoint. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a / or using complete URL, like this:

```
url: '/wp-content/plugins/matches/ajax-matches.php'
```

or this :

```
url: 'https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/matches/ajax-matches.php',
```

I can't send comment (don't have enough reputation) and this answer may cause me penalty, but still glad to help !

Comment: I appreciate the help. I tried both but the only time it worked was when i put it inside the public_html folder and in my ajax specified the url as 'ajax-matches.php'. Anything else doesn't work. Been trying to use admin-ajax but it appears to be tougher to do especially because I am still quite new to this stuff. Still digging. Thanks sir

Comment: My pleasure, do you have meta/base in head part ? It may cause some conflict. Also, I suggest to check .htaccess for RewriteRule.

Comment: I was able to use admin ajax as the url in place of what I had. Appreciate the help

Comment: I am glad you made, good lock :)